# Non-linear dependence between variables in multivariate linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I'm running a multivariate regression (1 dependent variable vs. ~20 independent variables). I noticed that the relationship between variables are quite non-linear. The below image is a histogram grouped into deciles of two **covariates** (histogram of the deciles of dependent vs. independent variables is a bit like that too but not as clear). What kind of relationship is this and how would this impact my linear regression?

[image]

Comment: You should probably determine goodness of fit from an actual model, using standard diagnostics with residuals etc., it is hard to predict what the model will be like just from this graph.

Comment: Thanks. $R^2$ is terrible (5-10%). So I'm wondering whether it's because the relationship is non-linear. And the residuals do seem to be correlated with the covariates

Comment: If you trained a simple `lm` model then use `plot(model)` to get diagnostics, there may be useful information about non/linearity in there.